# DO Droplet rg and node using up a lot of resource

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, digital-ocean

When I try to use vscode to manage my ubuntu droplet, I notice it's running really slowly and takes forever to open anything. I'm using it to learn concepts and just spun this up less than a week ago.

Taking a look at `top`, when I first open the server in vscode I see rg is at like 180%CPU, I also have a ton on snapd, node, and kswapd0. I'm not entirely sure what all these are. I did a bit of digging and rg is something to do with vscode?

I'd like to use vscode on linux but not if it crashes my server all the time and uses all my resource.

I'm not entirely sure what the nodes are. I don't have any node apps deployed. I'm only using mysql, docker, spring, nginx, certbot at the moment.

I noticed it was crashing so I updated to $18 a month 2vCPU and 2GB Memory, and it's still hitting 100% all the time. Is this because docker and spring is that resource intensive?

Edit: I have disabled built-in TS/JS feature extension. It's still pretty high. https://medium.com/good-robot/use-visual-studio-code-remote-ssh-sftp-without-crashing-your-server-a1dc2ef0936d
I have also disabled followSymLinks
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98594

[image: Resource]

[image: 184]

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: This may help describe what rg is doing.  ripgrep (rg). ripgrep is a line-oriented search tool that recursively searches the current directory for a regex pattern. By default, ripgrep will respect   Found with google search of 'what is ubuntu rg'.